# Classe_upload.php construct session empty

Tags: php, session, upload

I'm using this class: http://php.developpez.com/telecharger/detail/id/2944/Classe-d-upload-de-fichiers-avec-options-de-redimensionnement-renommage-gestion-des-erreurs

When I use the following code:

```
$repertoire_destination = strtolower($_SESSION['login']);

 //Déclaration de la classe
 $up = new Telechargement($repertoire_destination,'form1','file','controle_form');

 //Extensions autorisées (sans les .)
 $extensions = array("gif","png","jpg","jpeg");
 $up->Set_Extensions_accepte ($extensions);

 $name_fichier = uniqid($_SESSION['login']);
 // Rennommage des fichiers (en mode incrémentiel) si déjà présents sur le serveur.
 $up->Set_Nomme_fichier($name_fichier,pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
 $up->Set_Renomme_fichier($name_fichier);

 $up->Set_Redim ('1920','1200');
 $up->Set_Redim ('160','100','upload/'.strtolower($_SESSION['login']).'/thumb');


 // Téléchargement
 $up->Upload();
```

The uploaded file has to be saved in the directory:     `strtolower($_SESSION['login']);`
which `$_SESSION['login'])` contains the name of the user.

But unfortunately, it sends an empty value.

When I later use:

```
$up->Set_Redim ('160','100','upload/'.strtolower($_SESSION['login']).'/thumb');
```

the `$_SESSION['login'])` contains the `username`.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I understand French, and with the link you provided for your class, I fear that many others will not be able to read/understand what is inside that page. I'll see what I can do to help, but can't promise you anything. Try to find an equivalent link in English.

Comment: Yes I know... But unfortunately it doesn't exist and I doesn't have time to switch on a other upload class.

Comment: Now, is `session_start();` present/included in all the `.php` files you are using? It must be included if using sessions, plus it needs to be at the very top, underneath your opening PHP tag `<?php`. This is often overlooked.

Comment: please provide variable names and comments in English

Comment: Yes you right ... I didn't think about that because the second time session return value. Thanks !

Comment: @tomprouvost So did adding `session_start();` fix your problem?

Comment: Yes ! Thanks. I feel like a noob

Comment: @tomprouvost You're welcome. I will post it as answer and **accept** it in order to **mark** this question as being **solved**. I'm glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @tomprouvost Please **accept** my answer as being solved, otherwise it will remain in the **unanswered** category, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Answer (score 0):

`session_start();` must be present/included in all the .php files if using sessions.

Plus it needs to be at the very top (most of the time), 
underneath your opening PHP tag `<?php`.

**This is often overlooked.**

More information about sessions can be found on the PHP.net Web site by going to the following link.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php